# Create Powerpoint shape with hyperlink and text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am creating an index in powerpoint with links to other slides and it works fine to create the shapes and hyperlink attached to the shape, but I cannot get it to add text into the shape. At the moment I do it manually after the shape is created.

I have seen the method below but I get an error on the TexttoDisplay.
What am I doing wrong? Quite happy to use TextFrames if I can add the hyperlink to the frame rather than the text.

```
Sub CreateIndx()


' Create hyperlink to slide 2

Set pp = ActivePresentation


Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=215, Height:=30)
With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
.Action = ppActionHyperlink
.Hyperlink.Address = "..\War Memorial Slides\War Memorial Slides - Badlesmere to Elmley.pptx"
.Hyperlink.SubAddress = "1. Powerpoint Presentation"
        .TextToDisplay = "My Name"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try the following instead `sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "My Name"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other replies will solve the problem for you if you want text in the shape that you've created.  If instead you want to add a tool tip ... the little hint text that appears when you hover over the hyperlinked shape ... use this:

```
Sub CreateIndx()
' Create hyperlink to slide 2

' I'm a believer in dimming all variables
' Saves time/trouble in the long run
Dim pp As Presentation
Dim sh As Shape

Set pp = ActivePresentation

Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=215, Height:=30)
With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
.Action = ppActionHyperlink
End With

With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink
    .Address = "..\War Memorial Slides\War Memorial Slides - Badlesmere to Elmley.pptx"
    .SubAddress = "1. PowerPoint Presentation"
    .ScreenTip = "My Name"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Text:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateIndx()
    ' Create hyperlink to slide 2
    
    Dim pp
    Dim sh
    
    Set pp = ActivePresentation
    
    Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=215, Height:=30)
    With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
        .Hyperlink.Address = "..\War Memorial Slides\War Memorial Slides - Badlesmere to Elmley.pptx"
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = "1. Powerpoint Presentation"
    End With
    
    sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test" '<<< Your text here

End Sub
```